# Reordering x-axis by count descending in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following count plot in R

```
mpg %>%
  ggplot2::ggplot(ggplot2::aes(x = as.character(class))) +
  ggplot2::geom_bar(fill = '#00798c')  +
  ggplot2::geom_text(stat = "count", ggplot2::aes(label = after_stat(count)), position = ggplot2::position_dodge(width = 0.8), vjust = -0.3)
```

How can I reorder the bars to be by descending counts?

I'm not sure if I can use the
`reorder()` function here because there isn't a specific variable for the count. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use `reorder`. You are reordering by the length of each level, so do:

```r
library(ggplot2)

mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = reorder(factor(class), class, length))) +
  geom_bar(fill = '#00798c')  +
  geom_text(stat = "count", aes(label = after_stat(count)), 
                     position = position_dodge(width = 0.8), vjust = -0.3)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! what exactly does after_stat() do in this case?

Comment: It makes the calculated value `count` available to use as an aesthetic mapping. If you didn't have `after_stat`, ggplot would look for a variable called `count` in your data and throw an error because it doesn't exist there.

Answer (score 2):

We could use a combination: `fct_rev(fct_infreq(....` from `forcats` package it is in `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)
mpg %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = fct_rev(fct_infreq(as.character(class))))) +
  geom_bar(fill = '#00798c')  +
  geom_text(stat = "count", ggplot2::aes(label = after_stat(count)), 
            position = ggplot2::position_dodge(width = 0.8), vjust = -0.3)
```

[image]